# Sobriquet: Tap under the chin, origin unknown?

Tags: etymology, french

We see here https://www.etymonline.com/word/sobriquet and it says "origin unknown."

Is this to say, the connection between the literal meaning and the current meaning is unknown?

I would suggest that to chuck someone under the chin is a gesture of affection between intimate equals or, for example, an adult and a young child -- it is easy to see that someone might while doing this use a nickname. Not to be facetious, but if you have ever had a cat, that is exactly what happens if they have a nickname.

But maybe I am not understanding what "origin unknown" means in these etymologies.

Comment: *Is this to say, the connection between the literal meaning and the current meaning is unknown?* If we do not know the origin, then how would we know the literal meaning? If we don't know the literal meaning, how can your question be answered?

Comment: The literal meaning sounds like a chuck under the chin. It seems like they are saying they don't understand how that is related to nickname.

Comment: The dictionary says that the origin of the French word _soubriquet_ is unknown, and that it is _said to_ have meant a chuck under the chin, not _known to_.

Comment: *Origin unknown* means we don't know how it all began, who came up with it, and why it caught on. We know a nickname, for example, is a pet *name*, but why *nick*? If a dictionary cannot come up with the etymology of nickname, then *origin unknown* there, too. (Maybe "it is said to have" come from Nicholas->Nick.)

Comment: I believe the way you've asked the question was not well-received but I didn't downvote. "Origin unknown" here means it can't be traced back any further. Perhaps, you can just ask the origin of _sobriquet_ and you can cite the Etymonline for the research effort. There are some sources online with further information about the origin of _sobriquet_ and they try to explain how the French word was formed.

Comment: https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sobriquet

Answer (score 1):

Etymology does not deal directly with the **meanings** of words but mainly with the evolution over time of their **forms** and definitions. As with genealogy, a goal is to trace lineages. Ideally, we identify when a word was first used or attested and from which parent word it was created (its etymon). The same process is repeated for the parent word(s) and so on until we arrive at a word whose ancestors are unknown.

The English term "sobriquet" was borrowed from the French *sobriquet* in the mid-17th century. The French and English meanings were likely identical at that time. In modern French *sobriquets* are usually mocking or derogatory whereas I'm not sure this nuance is present in English.

The 17th century French *sobriquet* derives from the 16th century French *sobriquet* which had a different definition: "a chuck under the chin". Such changes in meaning are not uncommon.

When etymologists say that the origin of *sobriquet* is unknown, they are not saying that the change from "chuck" to "nickname" is unexplained but that the form *sobriquet* has at least one unknown etymon. It is suspected that the prefix *so-* comes from *sub* (French *sous*, under) as an alternative writing was *soubriquet*, but the root of *briquet* is unknown. Several hypotheses including the Latin *beccus* (beak) and the Dutch *bricke* (brick) have been rejected by etymologists as not convincing enough. Therefore, the origin of *sobriquet* is unknown. Q.E.D.